# Python: how parse this dict recursively?

Tags: python, recursion

I've a flat dict with entities. Each entity can have a parent. I'd like to recursively build each entity, considering the parent values.

Logic:

1. Each entity **inherits** defaults from its parent (e.g. `is_mammal`)
2. Each entity can **overwrite** the defaults of its parent (e.g. `age`)
3. Each entity can **add** new attributes (e.g. `hobby`)

I'm struggling to get it done. Help is appreciated, thanks!

```
entities = {
    'human': {
        'is_mammal': True,
        'age': None,
    },
    'man': {
        'parent': 'human', 
        'gender': 'male',
    },
    'john': {
        'parent': 'man',
        'age': 20,
        'hobby': 'football',
    }
};

def get_character(key):
    # ... recursive magic with entities ...
    return entity
    
john = get_character('john')
print(john)
```

Expected output:

```
{
    'is_mammal': True,  # inherited from human
    'gender': 'male'  # inherited from man
    'parent': 'man', 
    'age': 20, # overwritten
    'hobby': 'football', # added
}
```

Comment: Can entity have more than 1 parent? Can you have more than 2 levels of dictionaries?

Comment: @matszwecja each entity has one parent but the parent can have another parent: john -> man (parent) -> human (grand-parent). Yes, it can be infinite levels. It must be recursive. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would recommend you to add input with multiple person.

Comment: "Yes, it can be infinite levels": Can you clarify if you mean: 1. infinite? 2. any number, but finite? 3. Any finite small number (within default stack depth)

Comment: @Lesiak: realistically max. 10. Mostly 2-3.

Comment: I was mostly asking about if "parent" can contain a dict itself instead of another key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_character(entities, key):
    try:
        entity = get_character(entities, entities[key]['parent'])
    except KeyError:
        entity = {}
    entity.update(entities[key])
    return entity
```

Comment: btw Can the last two lines be just an `update()`?

Comment: @quamrana yes, yes they can.

Comment: Good, that's what I thought.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is using recursion and a Python quirk where mutables (here it's a dictionary `{}`), are shared among function calls. See the discussion below for why this is somewhat surprising, though useful for accumulating recursion results.

```
def get_character(d, key, entity = {}):
    if d.get(key) is None:
        return entity
    return get_character(d, d.get(key).get('parent'), d.get(key) | entity)

get_character(entities, 'john')

{'is_mammal': True,
 'age': 20,
 'parent': 'man',
 'gender': 'male',
 'hobby': 'football'}
```

Comment: Don't use dictionaries as default argumetns - ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/9296093)

Comment: But you're not actually accumulating results in this mutable. In fact, it never is anything else other than empty dictionary.

Comment: So while the code works, I think not using this argument would make the code more explicit and also not teach bad code practice.

Comment: It is getting updated at each iteration though?

Comment: Ok, my bad, although I'd still replace that with `get_character(d, key, entity = None)` and `if not entity: entity = {}` just to be 100% sure.

Comment: I won't because I don't see the point but I'll add a disclaimer.